# php-capture console output while processing a lengthy script

Tags: php, streaming, continuous, proc-open

I have an issue on capturing the ssh script output onto the browser as it executes rather than having it in the end.

Script written:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe","r"),
        1 => array("pipe","w"),
        2 => array("file","./error.log","a")
) ;
$cwd = 'path/path1' ;
for($counter=1;$counter<= 10;$counter++)
{
        $cmd="sudo test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3";
        $process = proc_open('ssh  user@server', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd) ;
        if (is_resource($process))
        {
          fwrite($pipes[0], $cmd) ;
         fclose($pipes[0]) ;
                echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]) ;
                  fclose($pipes[1]) ;
                $return_value = proc_close($process);
            echo "$counter=command returned $return_value<br>";
        }
}
```

Shell script takes 10mins to execute. If the $counter=10 then it taking too much time to get the real output thrown on screen. I require that it keeping on showing the stream output as it executes so that we know what's happening.
Is there case of buffering?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [flush() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php).

Comment: Thanks . You mean to say-  echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]) ;
                flush();

Comment: Thanks . You mean to say-  echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]) ;
                flush();
I tried this-                                                     if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();                            echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]) ;
                ob_flush();
                flush();
                usleep(50000);
it worked fine if script1 takes smaller times, but for script2 which takes time to execute then it goes in same time consuming issue.